# Codeigniter 3 application bug: unable to match password against password_hash

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a basic blog application in **Codeigniter 3.1.8** and **Bootstrap 4**.

The application allows Registration and Login.

The passwords used to be encrypted with the `md5()` function:

```
$enc_password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
```

In the Login **controller** I had:

```
public function login() {  
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
      $email = $this->input->post('email');
      $password = $this->input->post('password');
      $this->load->model('Usermodel');
      $current_user = $this->Usermodel->user_login($email, $password);
        // If we find a user
      if ($current_user) {
        // If the user found is active
        if ($current_user->active == 1) {
          $this->session->set_userdata(
           array(
            'user_id' => $current_user->id,
            'user_email' => $current_user->email,
            'user_first_name' => $current_user->first_name,
            'user_is_admin' => $current_user->is_admin,
            'user_active' => $current_user->active,
            'is_logged_in' => TRUE
            )
           );
          // After login, display flash message
          $this->session->set_flashdata('user_signin', 'You have signed in');
          //and redirect to the posts page
          redirect('/');  
        } else {
          // If the user found is NOT active
          $this->session->set_flashdata("login_failure_activation", "Your account has not been activated yet.");
          redirect('login'); 
        }
      } else {
        // If we do NOT find a user
        $this->session->set_flashdata("login_failure_incorrect", "Incorrect email or password.");
        redirect('login'); 
      }
    }
    else {
      $this->index();
    }
  }
```

and in the **model**:

```
public function user_login($email, $password) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('authors', ['email' => $email, 'password' => $hashed_password]);
    return $query->row();
}
```

I had security concerns so I replaced `md5()` with `password_hash()` in the **Register** controller:

```
$enc_password = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Registration works fine, with a more secure password string in the database then before.

I have updated the `user_login` in the User model to:

```
public function user_login($email, $password) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('authors', ['email' => $email, 'password' => $hashed_password]);
        return $query->row();
    }
```

where `$hashed_password` comes from the **Login** controller:

```
$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

This password matching, to my surprise, does not work.

What is the *minimal* amount of change in my login code that I must make for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have matched user-supplied password against `password_hash()`, with *minimal diferences* between the two versions of the code, by modifying `user_login()` to:

```
public function user_login($email, $password) {
    $pass_hash_query = $this->db
        ->select('password')
        ->get_where('authors', ['email' => $email]);

$pass_hash = $pass_hash_query->row()->password;

    if (password_verify($password, $pass_hash)) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('authors', ['email' => $email, 'password' => $pass_hash]);
        return $query->row();
    }
}
```

In the **Login controller** I have:

```
public function login() {  
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
      $email = $this->input->post('email');
      $password = $this->input->post('password');

      $this->load->model('Usermodel');
      $current_user = $this->Usermodel->user_login($email, $password);
        // If we find a user
      if ($current_user) {
        // If the user found is active
        if ($current_user->active == 1) {
          $this->session->set_userdata(
           array(
            'user_id' => $current_user->id,
            'user_email' => $current_user->email,
            'user_first_name' => $current_user->first_name,
            'user_is_admin' => $current_user->is_admin,
            'user_active' => $current_user->active,
            'is_logged_in' => TRUE
            )
           );
          // After login, display flash message
          $this->session->set_flashdata('user_signin', 'You have signed in');
          //and redirect to the posts page
          redirect('/');  
        } else {
          // If the user found is NOT active
          $this->session->set_flashdata("login_failure_activation", "Your account has not been activated yet.");
          redirect('login'); 
        }
      } else {
        // If we do NOT find a user
        $this->session->set_flashdata("login_failure_incorrect", "Incorrect email or password.");
        redirect('login'); 
      }
    }
    else {
      $this->index();
    }
}
```

I hope this is useful to many people other than me.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly check the strings if `password_hash` is used. Because it gives different string every time.

In order to check equality of your password, you need to use `password_verify` method.

You can get the whole document here.

LINK BELOW:

[securely-hash-passwords-with-php](https://jonsuh.com/blog/securely-hash-passwords-with-php/)

Comment: My friend, the OP answered his own question using `password_verify` about 8 hours before your answer.

Comment: I didn't see that he has answered his own question. However, I upvoted it. Thank You @DFriend